# Create folder in USB once mounted

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount

I am trying to create a folder in USB once it's mounted. I am using below udev rule where I am sending `**ID_FS_UUID_ENC** (64AC6F22AC6EEE4C)` as a parameter and in the `start.sh` I am creating a subfolder in this path - `/media/pi/64AC6F22AC6EEE4C`

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"  
# Import FS infos  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one  
#ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"  
#ENV{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}=="", ENV{dir_name}=""  
# Global mount options  
ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/usr/bin/setsid /home/pi/raspberry-stilas/start.sh %E{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"
ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo == >> /home/pi/raspberry-stilas/usb-storage-env.log; env >> /home/pi/raspberry-stilas/usb-storage-env.log'"
# Exit  
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

Now the problem is when I insert a USB `start.sh` creates a new folder and renames the passed one. So a new folder `64AC6F22AC6EEE4C` is created and USB label is renamed to `64AC6F22AC6EEE4C1`. Can anyone tell me what wrong I am doing? Is it that USB is not mounted and I am trying to create folder?

## Update

I checked syslog and my custom log it looks device is mounting after my script execution. Is there anything I can do to run only after mounting.

```
Custom Log - Stilas Python program run at 2019-05-18 11:33:01 PM
Syslog - May 18 23:33:02 raspberrypi udisksd[725]: Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/pi/64AC6F22AC6EEE4C1 on behalf of uid 1000
```

Log AFter adding `sleep 5`

```
May 19 01:33:40 raspberrypi kernel: [  944.893519] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
May 19 01:33:42 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.749507] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.880955] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=558a
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.880971] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.880980] usb 1-1.2: Product: Ultra
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.880988] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.880997] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 4C530001270213117013
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.881806] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi kernel: [  947.882227] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
May 19 01:33:43 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.890623] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra            1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.891609] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.891730] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 120127488 512-byte logical blocks: (61.5 GB/57.3 GiB)
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.892813] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.892828] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.893398] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.902832]  sdb: sdb1
May 19 01:33:44 raspberrypi kernel: [  948.905690] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 5
echo "Device Mounted on - `date +"%Y-%m-%d %r."` Path - /media/pi/{$1}" env >> /home/pi/raspberry-stilas/mount.log
if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
  echo "Stilas Python program run at `date +"%Y-%m-%d %r."` Path - /media/pi/{$1}" env >> /home/pi/raspberry-stilas/mount.log
  python3 /home/pi/raspberry-stilas/stilas/stilas.py "/media/pi/$1"
fi
```

Comment: This question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. It is a general Linux question.

Comment: Why do you not mount the USB drive in your script, sleep for five seconds, then create the folder ?

Comment: @thecarpy I tried some ways to mount it from code but it did not work. So I am using raspberry pi mounting options and then using udev to run my scripts. Even if I use sleep in my python script USB then does not mount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer suggesting to fork will no longer work with newer udev systems:

```
RUN
...
Starting daemons or other long running processes is not appropriate for
udev; the forked processes, detached or not, will be unconditionally killed
after the event handling has finished.
```

You could use a generic systemd servive that wants your `mount`, the device is mounted, you use: `sudo systemctl list-units -t mount` to find the systemd mount for your device, write down its name.

Then, you create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/your.service` 
`

```
[Unit] 
Description=My mount script trigger 
Requires=<whatever the command above returned>.mount 
After=<whatever the command above returned>.mount 

[Service] 
ExecStart=/home/pi/start.sh 

[Install] 
WantedBy=<whatever the command above returned>.mount
```

**Advantages**: easy to set up

**Disadvantages**: will only work for USB devices with a specific name. You have to work out the UUID yourself in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `/home/pi/start.sh` has a shebang (has `#!/bin/sh` on the very first line), `sleep 5` on line number 2, and the execute bit set (`chmod +x /home/pi/start.sh`).

Use `setsid`, it will fork, which means the script execution is performed in the background. The above sleep is there to give your system time to mount the USB device. Udev will not wait for the script to complete before it mounts the device, `setsid` will return immediately and the device should get mounted quickly.

`ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/usr/bin/setsid /home/pi/start.sh %E{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"`

EDIT: udev waits for all children, so the process has to create its own group.

Ensure `/home/pi/start.sh` has the following header:

```
#!/bin/sh
pgid_from_pid() {
    local pid=$1
    ps -o pgid= "$pid" 2>/dev/null | egrep -o "[0-9]+"
}

pid="$$"
if [ "$pid" != "$(pgid_from_pid $pid)" ]; then
    exec setsid "$(readlink -f "$0")" "$@"
fi
sleep 5
```

Create an init.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/pi/start.sh "$@"
```

Us that in combination of the following udev rule:

`ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="usb-storage", RUN+="/bin/sh /home/pi/init.sh %E{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"`

Comment: I tried this but once I set sleep 5, device does not mount.

Comment: Hm, interesting, what does the syslog say ?

Comment: I have added that log to my question

Comment: are you sure you used `setsid` ? It times out, so it is waiting ... maybe we could try and use a second shell script that we execute in the rule, that calls your current shell script with `setsid` then exits.

Comment: `RUN+="/usr/bin/setsid /home/pi/start.sh %E{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}"` is very important here, the `/usr/bin/setsid`

Comment: I have updated my question with the last log and other codes. Can you please recheck to see if that gives some clue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93807/discussion-between-irfan-and-thecarpy).

Answer (score 0):

> Needed to implement a thing that would react on USB Flash Drive
>   inserted (into autonomous BBB device) - to get device name, mount fs
>   there, rsync stuff to it, unmount.
>
> To avoid whatever concurrency issues (i.e. multiple things screwing
>   with device in parallel), proper error logging and other startup
>   things, most obvious thing is to wrap the script in a systemd oneshot
>   service.
>
> Only non-immediately-obvious problem for me here was how to pass
>   device to such service properly.
>
> With a bit of digging through google results (and even finding one
>   post here somehow among them), eventually found "Pairing udev's
>   SYSTEMD_WANTS and systemd's templated units" resolved thread, where
>   what seem to be current-best approach is specified.

Adapting it for my case and pairing with generic patterns for device-instantiated services, resulted in the following configuration.

udev rule:

```
ACTION=="add", PROGRAM="/usr/bin/systemd-escape -p --template=action-usb@.service %E{ID_FS_UUID_ENC}", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="%c"
```

action-usb@.service:

```
[Unit]
BindTo=%i.device
After=%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
TimeoutStartSec=300
ExecStart=/home/pi/raspberry-stilas/start.sh /%I
```

Adapted from [here](http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/01/12/starting-systemd-service-instance-for-device-from-udev.html).